# How are related the electrons magnetic dipole moments in atomic orbitals?

Tags: electronic-configuration, orbitals

I wondering, has somebody ever try to take in account the electrons magnetic dipole moment for the shapes of the probability distribution in atom? Does this magnetic dipole moment play any role in the inner bounds of molecules?

Comment: Some thoughts of mine see here: https://www.academia.edu/18391675/About_the_distribution_of_the_electrons_magnetic_dipole_moments_in_the_atoms_Part_1

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In my paper, mentioned above, I have had some doubts about the role of the electrons dipole moment distribution in chromium atom which is quite symmetrical if I use my octahedral model instead of s- and p-orbitals.

Now a have read on Wikipedia about the [magnetic characteristics of pure chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium#Characteristics): "Chromium is remarkable for its magnetic properties: it is the only elemental solid which shows antiferromagnetic ordering at room temperature (and below). Above 38 °C, it transforms into a paramagnetic state." This matches perfect into my model abot octahedral structure of neon and argon shell electrons.